# KafkaConsumer is going into indefinite wait state while polling

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to poll kafka topic using KafkaConsumer API. But it is going into indefinite wait state and not honoring even if we pass timeout for polling.

From thread dump it is showing Runnable state, I took multiple thread dumps always main thread stays at same position, I believe it is not coming out of wait.

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f42a800f000 nid=0x59 runnable [0x00007f42b0782000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000006c02e2088> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
        - locked <0x00000006c02e2078> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000006c02e1f60> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:425)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:254)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:270)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:303)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:197)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:187)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.awaitMetadataUpdate(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:126)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorKnown(AbstractCoordinator.java:186)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:857)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:829)
        at org.test.TestReceiver(TestReceiver:100)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Here is the code snippet..only the first log getting printed.

```
LOG.info("Going to wait {}ms for ConsumerRecords", POLLING_TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(POLLING_TIMEOUT_MILLIS); 
LOG.info("Received {} ConsumerRecords to process.", (records != null ? records.count() : null));
```

Library versions...

kafka_2.11:jar:0.9.0.0

kafka-clients:jar:0.9.0.0

Answer (score 4):

`KafkaConsumer#poll()` might block if it need to refresh its metadata but cannot connect to the cluster.

Addressed via KIP-266: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=75974886

Answer (score 0):

Noticed below error in kafka, after configuring **offsets.topic.replication.factor=1** in server.properties issue got solved.

```
ERROR [KafkaApi-0] Number of alive brokers '1' does not meet the required replication factor '3' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet. (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
```